# Jquery Serialize data

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, post, jquery-validate

So I have several text boxes, drop down menus, and radio options on this form. When the user clicks submit i want to save ALL that information so I can put it into a database. So this is all the form's inputs

```
<div id="reg2a">
First Name: <br/><input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/>
Last Name: <br/><input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/>
Address: <br/><input type="text" name="address" /> <br/>
City: <br/><input type="text" name="city" /> <br/>
State: <br/><input type="text" name="state" /> <br/>
Zip Code: <br/><input type="text" name="zip" /> <br/>
Phone Number: <br/><input type="text" name="phone" /> <br/>
Fax: <br/><input type="text" name="fax" /> <br/>
Email: <br/><input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
Ethnicity: <i>Used only for grant reporting purposes</i> <br/><input type="text" name="ethnicity" /> <br/><br/>

Instutional Information Type (select the best option) <br/>
<select name="iitype">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="uni">University</option>
<option value="commorg">Community Organization</option>
</select> <br/><br/>

    Number of sessions willing to present:
    <select id="vennum_select" name="vnum">
      <?php for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
      <?php } ?><br/>
    </select><br/>
    Number of tables requested:
    <select id="tabnum_select" name="tnum">

      <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select><br/><br/>
    Awarding of a door prize during the conference will result in a reduction in the cost of your first table. <br/><br/>
    I am providing a door prize for delivery during the conference of $75 or more
    <select id="prize_select" name="pnum">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>  
    </select><br/>

Prize name: <input type="text" name="prize_name" /><br/>
Description: <input type="text" name="descr" /><br/>
Value: <input type="text" name="retail" /><br/><br/>

Name of Institution: <br/><input type="text" name="institution" /> <br/><br/>

Type (select the best option) <br/>
<select name="type">
<option value="none">None</option>
<option value="k5">K-5</option>
<option value="k8">K-8</option>
<option value="68">6-8</option>
<option value="912">9-12</option>
</select> <br/><br/>

Address: <br/><input type="text" name="address_sch" /> <br/>
City: <br/><input type="text" name="city_sch" /> <br/>
State: <br/><input type="text" name="state_sch" /> <br/>
Zip Code: <br/><input type="text" name="zip_sch" /> <br/>

<form name="frm2sub" id="frm2sub" action="page3.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

This is my jquery function:

```
$("#frm2sub").submit( function() {  
    var values = {};
values["fname"] = $("#fname").val();
});
```

I can do this for each one of the input boxes but I want to give all this data to the next page. So how do I put this array into $_POST? Btw, I've tried doing

```
var data = $("#reg2a").serialize();
```

and

```
var data = $(document).serialize();
```

Data ended up being empty. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap all input elements within the form tag. Then all data will be available in the $_POST variable in page3.php

Like this:

```
<form name="frm2sub" id="frm2sub" action="page3.php" method="post">
    <div id="reg2a">
    First Name: <br/><input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/>
    Last Name: <br/><input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/>
    Address: <br/><input type="text" name="address" /> <br/>
    City: <br/><input type="text" name="city" /> <br/>
    State: <br/><input type="text" name="state" /> <br/>
    Zip Code: <br/><input type="text" name="zip" /> <br/>
    Phone Number: <br/><input type="text" name="phone" /> <br/>
    Fax: <br/><input type="text" name="fax" /> <br/>
    Email: <br/><input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
    Ethnicity: <i>Used only for grant reporting purposes</i> <br/><input type="text" name="ethnicity" /> <br/><br/>

    Instutional Information Type (select the best option) <br/>
    <select name="iitype">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="uni">University</option>
    <option value="commorg">Community Organization</option>
    </select> <br/><br/>

        Number of sessions willing to present:
        <select id="vennum_select" name="vnum">
          <?php for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
          <?php } ?><br/>
        </select><br/>
        Number of tables requested:
        <select id="tabnum_select" name="tnum">

          <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select><br/><br/>
        Awarding of a door prize during the conference will result in a reduction in the cost of your first table. <br/><br/>
        I am providing a door prize for delivery during the conference of $75 or more
        <select id="prize_select" name="pnum">
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>  
        </select><br/>

    Prize name: <input type="text" name="prize_name" /><br/>
    Description: <input type="text" name="descr" /><br/>
    Value: <input type="text" name="retail" /><br/><br/>

    Name of Institution: <br/><input type="text" name="institution" /> <br/><br/>

    Type (select the best option) <br/>
    <select name="type">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="k5">K-5</option>
    <option value="k8">K-8</option>
    <option value="68">6-8</option>
    <option value="912">9-12</option>
    </select> <br/><br/>

    Address: <br/><input type="text" name="address_sch" /> <br/>
    City: <br/><input type="text" name="city_sch" /> <br/>
    State: <br/><input type="text" name="state_sch" /> <br/>
    Zip Code: <br/><input type="text" name="zip_sch" /> <br/>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />

    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to place a form around the inputs and then give the form an ID and use jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function. This will give you a URL encoded string of all the values.

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize the ID of your FORM tag. But really You aren't using AJAX anyway to post the form, so $_POST just comes by actually POSTING the data. Use

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```

Then just submit and $_POST will hold your data...

Answer (score 0):

Your form has no tags around.  Add the form tags and serialize that. This will take all elements inside the form

```
$('#myform').serialize();
```